# How to update apache, mysql, phpmyadmin and php on Raspbian?

Tags: apache-httpd, upgrade, mysql, php, phpmyadmin

I have my own web server running on my raspberry pi, and all my programs are outdated. I would like to update my PHP, Apache, MySQL, and phpMyAdmin. Can anyone tell me how to update all of these?

I'm running a Debian distro called raspbian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enter some commands into the command line. First of all:

```
sudo apt update
```

(this will update the sources of software)

and then

```
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

(this will upgrade everything to the latest version)